Why is the Quran text called verse?
I know that the Quran is not comparable to poetry style because it's divine, but why is the text of the Quran called "verse" ?
I couldn't find any information on it.
And in Arabic it's called "Ayah".

Can you give a couple of examples from reputable sources showing this usage, please, Mike? M-W sense 2a/3  (see M-W) gives a pretty broad sense, with emphasis on ' imaginative awareness of experience' through the writing; there is a 'non-ordinary' / 'rhythms of experience addressed' allusion.

Sections of the Bible are also called (chapters and) verses, but it's not poetry (except the Psalms, perhaps). A verse may consist of more than one sentence, and a sentence may span more than one verse.

Cambridge Dictionary has for verse: one of the series of short parts that the writing of a holy book is divided into. Did you look at the Online Etymology Dictionary?

Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary (2003) lists sura (Arabic for "row," and the rough equivalent in the Quran of chapters in the Bible) as a full-fledged English word. In contrast, the only definition it gives for ayah is "a nurse or maid native to India."

@SvenYargs a sutra is a text from other religions.

Why the assumption that a holy book can't be "poetry ... because it's divine"? Not commenting on the Quran in particular.

@WeatherVane: This is the Eleventh Collegiate's definition of sura (which it dates to 1667 in English): "a chapter of the Koran." In contrast, sutra is a Sanskrit word that means, literally, "thread" (and etymologically related to both sew and suture). Its original meaning in English usage was in reference to "a precept summarizing Vedic teaching; also : a collection of these precepts."
